# 'truffle compile': TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type tuple(uint256,address)

Tags: solidity, javascript, truffle-compile

Attempting to test this repo in Ubuntu 18.04: https://github.com/ETH-Pantheon/Aion

```
Truffle v4.1.14 (core: 4.1.14)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)
```

Here is the main contract I've already deployed to my testnet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24; 

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Client contract.
 This contract is generated for each user (user account). All the transactions of a user are executed from this contract.
 Only Aion smart contract can interact with the user account and only when the user schedules transactions.
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

contract AionClient {

    address private AionAddress;

    constructor(address addraion) public{
        AionAddress = addraion;
    }


    function execfunct(address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, bytes data) external returns(bool) {
        require(msg.sender == AionAddress);
        return to.call.value(value).gas(gaslimit)(data);

    }


    function () payable public {}

}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SafeMat library
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
library SafeMath {
  /** @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.*/
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {return 0;}
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

  /** @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.*/
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

  /**@dev Substracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).*/
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

  /** @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.*/
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
        return c;
    }

}



/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aion Smart contract (by ETH-Pantheon)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

contract Aion {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public owner;
    uint256 public serviceFee;
    uint256 public AionID;
    uint256 public feeChangeInterval;
    mapping(address => address) public clientAccount;
    mapping(uint256 => bytes32) public scheduledCalls;

    // Log for executed transactions.
    event ExecutedCallEvent(address indexed from, uint256 indexed AionID, bool TxStatus, bool TxStatus_cancel, bool reimbStatus);

    // Log for scheduled transactions.                        
    event ScheduleCallEvent(uint256 indexed blocknumber, address indexed from, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit,
                            uint256 gasprice, uint256 fee, bytes data, uint256 indexed AionID, bool schedType);

    // Log for cancelation of a scheduled call (no fee is charged, all funds are moved from client's smart contract to client's address)                        
    event CancellScheduledTxEvent(address indexed from, uint256 Total, bool Status, uint256 indexed AionID);


    // Log for changes in the service fee
    event feeChanged(uint256 newfee, uint256 oldfee);




    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        serviceFee = 500000000000000;
    }    

    // This function allows to change the address of the owner (admin of the contract)
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        withdraw();
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    // This function creates an account (contract) for a client if his address is 
    // not yet associated to an account
    function createAccount() internal {
        if(clientAccount[msg.sender]==address(0x0)){
            AionClient newContract = new AionClient(address(this));
            clientAccount[msg.sender] = address(newContract);
        }
    }



    /* This function schedules transactions: client should provide an amount of Ether equal to value + gaslimit*gasprice + serviceFee
    @param blocknumber block or timestamp at which the transaction should be executed. 
    @param to recipient of the transaction.
    @param value Amount of Wei to send with the transaction.
    @param gaslimit maximum amount of gas to spend in the transaction.
    @param gasprice value to pay per unit of gas.
    @param data transaction data.
    @param schedType determines if the transaction is scheduled on blocks or timestamp (true->timestamp)
    @return uint256 Identification of the transaction
    @return address address of the client account created
    */
    function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint,address){
        require(msg.value == value.add(gaslimit.mul(gasprice)).add(serviceFee));
        AionID = AionID + 1;
        scheduledCalls[AionID] = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blocknumber, msg.sender, to, value, gaslimit, gasprice, serviceFee, data, schedType));
        createAccount();
        clientAccount[msg.sender].transfer(msg.value);
        emit ScheduleCallEvent(blocknumber, msg.sender, to, value, gaslimit, gasprice, serviceFee, data, AionID, schedType);
        return (AionID,clientAccount[msg.sender]);
    }


    /* This function executes the transaction at the correct time/block
    Aion off-chain system should provide the correct information for executing a transaction.
    The information is checked against the hash of the original data provided by the user saved in scheduledCalls.
    If the information does not match, the transaction is reverted.
    */
    function executeCall(uint256 blocknumber, address from, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice,
                         uint256 fee, bytes data, uint256 aionId, bool schedType) external {
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        if(schedType) require(blocknumber <= block.timestamp);
        if(!schedType) require(blocknumber <= block.number);

        require(scheduledCalls[aionId]==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blocknumber, from, to, value, gaslimit, gasprice, fee, data, schedType)));
        AionClient instance = AionClient(clientAccount[from]);

        require(instance.execfunct(address(this), gasprice*gaslimit+fee, 2100, hex"00"));
        bool TxStatus = instance.execfunct(to, value, gasleft().sub(50000), data);

        // If the user tx fails return the ether to user
        bool TxStatus_cancel;
        if(!TxStatus && value>0){TxStatus_cancel = instance.execfunct(from, value, 2100, hex"00");}

        delete scheduledCalls[aionId];
        bool reimbStatus = from.call.value((gasleft()).mul(gasprice)).gas(2100)();
        emit ExecutedCallEvent(from, aionId,TxStatus, TxStatus_cancel, reimbStatus);

    }


    /* This function allows clients to cancel scheduled transctions. No fee is charged.
    Parameters are the same as in ScheduleCall.
    @return bool indicating success or failure.
    */
    function cancellScheduledTx(uint256 blocknumber, address from, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice,
                         uint256 fee, bytes data, uint256 aionId, bool schedType) external returns(bool) {
        if(schedType) require(blocknumber >=  block.timestamp+(3 minutes) || blocknumber <= block.timestamp-(5 minutes));
        if(!schedType) require(blocknumber >  block.number+10 || blocknumber <= block.number-20);
        require(scheduledCalls[aionId]==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(blocknumber, from, to, value, gaslimit, gasprice, fee, data, schedType)));
        require(msg.sender==from);
        AionClient instance = AionClient(clientAccount[msg.sender]);

        bool Status = instance.execfunct(from, value+gasprice*gaslimit+fee, 3000, hex"00");
        require(Status);
        emit CancellScheduledTxEvent(from, value+gasprice*gaslimit+fee, Status, aionId);
        delete scheduledCalls[aionId];
        return true;
    }




    // This function allows the owner of the contract to retrieve the fees and the gas price
    function withdraw() public {
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }


    // This function updates the service fee.
    // To provide security to the clients the fee can only be updated once per day.
    // This is to maintain the same price despite the Ether variation.
    // Also, the amount of the update (if increased) can only increase 10% each time.
    // Furthermore, an event is fired when the fee has been changed to inform the network.
    function updatefee(uint256 fee) public{
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        require(feeChangeInterval<block.timestamp);
        uint256 oldfee = serviceFee;
        if(fee>serviceFee){
            require(((fee.sub(serviceFee)).mul(100)).div(serviceFee)<=10);
            serviceFee = fee;
        } else{
            serviceFee = fee;
        }
        feeChangeInterval = block.timestamp + (1 days);
        emit feeChanged(serviceFee, oldfee);
    } 



    // fallback- receive Ether
    function () public payable {

    }



}
```

Here's my example contract, Sched.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// interface Aion
contract Aion {
uint256 public serviceFee;
function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint);
function cancellScheduledTx(uint256 blocknumber, address from, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice,
                     uint256 fee, bytes data, uint256 aionId, bool schedType) external returns(bool);

}

// Main contract
contract MyContract{
Aion aion;
address aionAccount;

function scheduleTransaction(uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bool time_or_block) public {
    aion = Aion(0xD916EdFd054E1c0fE8e0979DF3818bd60313Bc62); //contract address of deployed Aion contract to interact with
    uint256 callCost = value + gaslimit*gasprice + aion.serviceFee();
    uint256 txId;
    (txId,aionAccount) = aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)(block.number+15, address(this), value, gaslimit, gasprice,hex"00",time_or_block);
}

function () public payable {}

}
```

When I run truffle compile, I get the following error:

```
/home/melvin/schedule/contracts/Sched.sol:21:23: TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type tuple(uint256,address).
(txId,aionAccount) = aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)(block.number+15, address(this), value, gaslimit, gasprice,hex"00",time_or_block);    
                     ^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Any ideas? I'm not great with Solidity yet, if you think it's something simple, it probably is, let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in this declaration add address in along with uint in the returns

```
function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint,address);
```

Then it would work.

Comment: That worked, and makes sense, equal input and output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ScheduleCall`returns `uint` and you are trying to assign that type to a `tuple(uint, address)`.

So you might want to do something like this:

```
(txId,aionAccount) = (aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)(block.number+15, address(this), value, gaslimit, gasprice,hex"00",time_or_block), theAionAccountHere);
```

Not sure this would work but seems logical to me.